# Reference request: completion of Banach norm on sum

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X_1,X_2$ be Banach subspaces of a locally convex space $X$.  Then the subset
$$
X_1+X_2 = \left\{
x\in X:\, x= \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 \, \beta_i \in \mathbb{R},\, x_i \in X_i
\right\},
$$
a is a normed space with respect to the norm
$$
\|x\| := \inf\left\{
\sum_{i=1}^2|\beta_i|\|x_i\|_i: x = x_1 +x_2, \beta_i \in \mathbb{R}
\right\}
$$
where $\|x_i\|_i$ is the norm of the element $x_i \in X_i$  and the infimum is taken over all representations of $x$ as the sum of elements in $X_1$ and $X_2$.  Furthermore, the closure of $X_1+X_2$ in $X$ is Banach with respect to the completion of the norm $\|\cdot\|$.

What's a reference to this fact?

Comment: Maybe  the definition of $\|x\|$ it's just the infimum of $\|x_1\|+\|x_2\|$, without $|\beta_i|$  (otherwise you get $0$, as it is).

Comment: Oh, I gave that as an exercise in a functional analysis final examination 3 years ago (exercise 2). In case you read Italian... https://www.dropbox.com/s/sjo09f70jt9ofpj/soluzioni-IAM-I-2017.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Actually, I do read abit of Italian :)

Comment: This has a simple one line proof using very basic facts about Banach spaces: the map $(x,y) \mapsto x+y$ is a surjection from the product of $X_1$ and $X_2$ onto your space and this displays it as the quotient of a Banach space by a closed subspace

Comment: I know but I needed to save space in a paper (the journal has limits on the paper but not on the appendix).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You find it in the manuscript of Alessandra Lunardi on Interpolation Theory. A free version is available here: http://people.dmi.unipr.it/alessandra.lunardi/LectureNotes/SNS1999.pdf

In these notes the argument is (somewhat compressed) on page 3.

If you want a ZBL reference, then see page ix in

*Lunardi, Alessandra*, Interpolation theory, Appunti. Pisa: Scuola Normale Superiore. 149 p. (1999). [ZBL1165.41300](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1165.41300).

It is the same text.

Comment: This is fantastic.  Thank you very much Andras! :))